# Click Button RSelenium Amazon Page Turn

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am unable to get Rselenium to turn the page on an Amazon Review section I am attempting to scrape.  Below is my code.  I have tried almost every combination of CSS and xpath possible.  Any thoughts?

```
       replicate(100,
          {
remDr$navigate("https://www.amazon.com/Eagles-Nest-Outfitters-DoubleNest-Portable/product-reviews/B00K30GXK8/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviewshttps://www.amazon.com/Eagles-Nest-Outfitters-DoubleNest-Portable/product-reviews/B00K30GXK8/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
morereviews <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".a-last a")
morereviews$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(4)

reviews <- xml2::read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])%>%
  rvest::html_nodes(".review-text")%>%
  dplyr::data_frame(reviews = .)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to use `RSelenium` but only `rvest`. First, you can scrape the reviews of one of these pages reading the html directly. Second, note that every time you turn the page on the Reviews section, the url also changes (actually, it indicates the page number that you're seeing). Therefore, you can use a loop where you change the url and scrape all the reviews:

```
reviews <- lapply(1:100,
       function(i){
         url <- paste0("https://www.amazon.com/Eagles-Nest-Outfitters-DoubleNest-Portable/product-reviews/B00K30GXK8/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_",i,"?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviewshttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FEagles-Nest-Outfitters-DoubleNest-Portable%2Fproduct-reviews%2FB00K30GXK8%2Fref%3Dcm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm%3Fie%3DUTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=",i)
         xml2::read_html(url) %>%
           rvest::html_nodes(".review-text") %>%
           rvest::html_text() %>%
           dplyr::data_frame(reviews = .)
       })
(reviews <- do.call("rbind", reviews))
```

Comment: Thanks pol!  I have a tendency to overcomplicate things.  The code works!  Curious though if you know how to do the click in RSelenium for future use?

Comment: Hey Stack.  Any chance you can give me a tip on how to get Rselenium to click the page?  This problem is bothering me.